# Firebase getting specific parent not all children SWIFT

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, but I can't figure this out for the life of me. I am using Xcode and Swift 4.

I want to read a certain child level from Firebase to make a tableView based on the results there. Below is my Firebase data:

[image: Firebase Data.]

I want to make a tableView that lists Bill and Josh which is under "subNames" I seem to only make a snapshot that includes all of Bill and Josh's children as well. I just want the list of items directly in the subNames child. Anybody know how to do this? I am sure I am missing something..

This is my code:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

var refHandle: UInt!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    ref = Database.database().reference() 

}

func loadmoreData () {

    refHandle = ref?.child("Users").child(FBuid).observe(.value, with : { (snapshot) in

        let mynamesArray = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "subNames")

        print (mynamesArray)
    })
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include how you initialize `ref`.

Comment: I re-uploaded the code.. When I run this code, I am getting the result of:  Snap (subNames) {
    Bill =     {
        name = Bill;
        thissubUID = SZL9yf6EwRS5XJZIU6uQfhTfBmT2;
    };
    Josh =     {
        name = Josh;
        thissubUID = McJWwodagxaqfOl0NSzoz4MwLrB2;
    };
}  But, I only want the result of Bill and Josh.

Comment: To be more correct, I want a result of ["Bill","Josh"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an array with just the keys under `subNames`, you'll need something like  this:

```
refHandle = ref?.child("Users").child(FBuid).child("subNames").observe(.value, with : { (snapshot) in

  let mynamesArray = [String]()

  for child in snapshot.children {
    mynamesArray.append(child.key)
  }

  print (mynamesArray)
})
```

Comment: Hi Frank.. Thanks so much for the answer.. That is wonderful..I think I don't fully understand the .key part of that.. but it works great.. I did have to correct one line of code to be:  mynamesArray.append((child as AnyObject).key)

Comment: The keys are the names of nodes, so the `Bill` and `Josh` strings in your case. The thing under a key is its value, available through the `value` property of  snapshot.